# Modeling an optimization problem as linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

[image]

### Attempt:

First, I call $x$ be the number of shafts produced per year and $y$ the number of frames produced per year. We have that each machine works at most $4500$ hours. we can place all of our data in the following table:

[image]

Thus, we want to maximize $f(x,y) = x+y$ subject to

$$ 0.6 x + 0.8 y \leq 90 000 $$
$$ 0.3 x + 0 y \leq 22 500 $$
$$ 0.4 x + 0.6 y \leq 45 000 $$
$$ 0x + 0.2 y \leq 135 00 $$
$$ 0x + 0.3 y \leq 27 000 $$

and obviously $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0 $

Is this the correct formulation?

Comment: Can a forging machine process a shaft and a frame at the same time?

Comment: no, I dont think so.

Comment: Since fractional shafts and frames are probably not desired, you should add $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. This, however, turns your LP into a MIP.

Comment: What is an MIP? But, as far as the modeling is concerned, am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your model is not correct. Solving the model with an LP-solver yields the solution $x=75000$ and $y=25000$. I assume, however, that for every frame you also need a shaft. Hence, you need to add the following constraint:

$$x=y$$

Solving the problem with the additional constraint yields the solution $x=y=45000$. Please note that luckily the number of shafts/frames in the solution is an integer. This need not happen always. Thus, you should also add the constraints $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ in general, even though these were not needed here.

Comment: the constraint is $x \geq y$ (not $x=y$)

Comment: @LinAlg Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: The requirement "for every frame you also need a shaft" means that the number of shafts needs to be at least the number of frames (so $x \geq y$). Your solution probably remains optimal though.

Comment: @LinAlg In the original problem it did not say "for every frame you also need  a shaft" but that the assembly consists "of a frame, a shaft, and a ball bearing". The other quote was by me and was due to that in the author's own problem formulation one would have obtained a higher number of frames than shafts. I still think that my constraint is correct in terms of the text in the author's post. It is just my wording that caused the confusion.